# Translation of "Take a toll"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

> The problems of the past few months have taken their toll on her health and there are shadows under her eyes.
>
> The deepening recession has also taken its toll in the south of the country, where unemployment is rife.

Google translate gives **des effets/conséquences néfastes** as interpretation:

> Les problèmes de ces derniers mois ont eu des effets néfastes sur sa
> santé et des ombres se cachent sous ses yeux.
>
> L’aggravation de la récession a également eu des conséquences néfastes
> dans le sud du pays, où le chômage sévit.

[Lingue](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/take+a+toll.html) provides a couple of other expressions, according to the context. I guess a literal translation (prends un péage:-)!) does not make sense in French. But, I wonder if there are other ways (idiomatic expressions) to express the same meaning.

Comment: Au prix de l'inversion du sujet, on pourrait dire de façon idiomatique que : *elle (ou sa santé) a **payé [les / le prix des]** problèmes de ces derniers mois.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal translation of *prendre un péage* doesn't make sense indeed. An idiomatic and semantically close French expression can be ***faire payer un lourd tribut*** but it is a little stronger and hard to use it with your first example.

With both of them, *to take a toll* might be translated by *affecter*:

> Les problèmes de ces derniers mois ont **affecté** sa santé et des **cernes** sont visibles sous ses yeux.
>
> L’aggravation de la récession a également **lourdement affecté** le sud du pays, où le chômage est omniprésent.
>
> L’aggravation de la récession a aussi **fait payer un lourd tribut** au sud du pays, où le chômage est omniprésent.

Answer (score 1):

Je le traduirais comme « ça s'est resenti sur sa santé » ou « ça a porté atteinte à sa santé ». Je ne peux pas penser à quelque chose de plus proche.

Answer (score -1):

De façon assez littérale on peut utiliser le verbe « dégrader », pour le moins dans tous les cas cités en l'adaptant, comme pour la seconde possibilité (causer une dégradation); du point de vue de préserver le ton imagé de la phrase anglaise la possibilité suivante est intéressante : « prendre sa part de butin ».

> Les problèmes de ces derniers mois ont dégradé sa santé et des ombres se cachent sous ses yeux.
>       L’aggravation de la récession a également causé une dégradation dans  le sud du pays, où sévit aussi le chômage .
>
> Les problèmes de ces derniers mois ont pris leur part de butin sur sa santé et des ombres se cachent sous ses yeux.
>       L’aggravation de la récession a également pris sa part de butin dans le sud du pays, où le chômage sévit.

Comment: De ma part +1. Cependant, étant non natif je n'arrive pas à comprendre les votes négatives. Y a-t-il des fautes ?

Comment: @dimitris  Ces votes négatifs sont le résultat d'erreurs que j'ai corrigées, c'est à dire que l'on ne voit plus les erreurs; les votes étaient normaux dans le passé, maintenant je sais pas, ils pourraient être normaux à mon avis s'il n'y a plus d'erreur grave, mais c'est une question de convention. Merci de vous soucier de ce petit problème.